# Есть ли возможность работать с JSON файлом который лежит в /assets

Tags: java, android, json, android-assets

Имеется плеер, который подгружает данные с JSON файла, расположенного в папке `/assets`.
Возможно ли работать внутри приложения с этим JSON файлом?
То есть удалять из него данные, добавлять и т.д?

Пример содержимого в файле JSON:

```
  [
          {
            "commercials": true,
            "description": "Описание..",
            "iconUrl": "http://site.ru/name.png",
            "name": "Name 2 Example",
            "network": "Genre Jumor",
            "stationUrl": "jumor,radio",
            "streams": [
              "http://site.ru/music1.mp3"
            ]
          },
          {
            "commercials": true,
            "description": "Описание..",
            "iconUrl": "http://site.ru/name.png",
            "name": "Name 1 Example",
            "network": "Genre Jumor",
            "stationUrl": "jumor,radio",
            "streams": [
              "http://site.ru/music2.mp3"
            ]
          },
          {
            "commercials": true,
            "description": "Описание..",
            "iconUrl": "http://site.ru/name.png",
            "name": "Name 3 Example",
            "network": "Genre Jumor",
            "stationUrl": "jumor,radio",
            "streams": [
              "http://site.ru/music3.mp3"
            ]
          }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Содержимое папки `assets` упаковывается в `apk` при сборке приложения и потому доступно только для чтения.

Если для файлов, которые хранятся в `assets`, предполагается возможность изменения, их требуется скопировать в память устройства или на SD карту и редактировать уже там. Естественно, что после этого считывать данные нужно уже из скопированного файла.

Также не стоит забывать и о разрешениях, которые необходимы приложению для подобных действий.